# Ionic 2 Grid System Height Issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass, ionic2

**The Goal:**

[image: from app.moqups.com]

So, the header is at the top, and the footer is at the bottom.

ITs inbetween im having issues with.

currently my html is:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="amount-r" justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-col col-auto align-self-start text-center>
        <p class="amount" [innerHtml]="amount"></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="source-r" justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-col col-7>
        <ion-row align-items-end justify-content-center>
          <ion-col col-auto text-end>
            <p class="cpa-card-p" color="light">(Source:
              <ion-icon class="cpa-card-icon" name="card" ion-text color="light"></ion-icon>
              <span>{{source}}</span> )
            </p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-5>
        <ion-row align-items-start justify-content-center>
          <ion-col col-auto text-start>
            <button (tap)="changeSource()" ion-button clear no-padding no-margin>
            <p no-padding no-margin style="text-decoration: underline;" ion-text color="e-green">change</p>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="numpad-r" align-items-center justify-content-center>
      <numpad (pinUpdated)="numInput($event)"></numpad>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

And the three relevant classes are amount-r, source-r, numpad-r. My thought was just to give them percentages and align their content according to the design. But as soon as I ad percentages, the ion-grid height goes to zero. How do I space this all out? The recent Ionic updates changed all the styling on me.

Any advice or examples for a flow like this would be much appreciated.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```